# How to get entity class by database table name?

Tags: java, jpa

Is it possible to get the Entity class Name from table Name? I am using JPA.

I have the table name. I am able to get the primary keys of the table. Now i want to retrieve a tuple from the table. I need the tuple in the form of entity object or in the form of string array.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify your question please? It's too abstract. Maybe some code of what you are trying to do? thanks

Answer (score 4):

Since Java Persistence 2.0 you can use [`Metamodel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/metamodel/Metamodel.html) to do so:

```
public Class<?> getTypeForTableName(String tableName) {
  for (EntityType<?> entityType : getEntityManager().getMetamodel().getEntities()) {
    if (entityType.getJavaType().getAnnotation(Table.class).name().equals(tableName)) {
      return entityType.getJavaType();
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```